# Trig values of $45^\circ+\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin\alpha=\dfrac{4}{5}$ and $\alpha\in(45^\circ;90^\circ)$ find the values of the other trig functions of $\alpha$ and the values of the trig functions of $45^\circ+\alpha$.

Using the indentity $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$ I got that $\cos\alpha=\dfrac35,\tan\alpha=\dfrac43$ and $\cot\alpha=\dfrac34.$ How can I find the values of the trig functions of $45^\circ+\alpha?$

Comment: $\sin 45^0 = \cos 45^0 = 1 / \sqrt2$. So $\sin (45^0 + \alpha) = \sin 45^0 (\sin \alpha + \cos \alpha)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$\sin(A+B) = \sin A \cos B+ \cos A \sin B$
$\cos(A+B) = \cos A\cos B-\sin A \sin B $

[image]

To prove using unit circle:

[image]

Equate $PQ_1 = RT$ because both the angles are equal
https://medium.com/@nubtrek/easy-with-sin-a-b-proof-vuja-de-50c15fca3344

Comment: I haven't studied these formulas.

Comment: @nicoledobreva Then you will have to use geometry. I will add an image for reference. Just take $B = 45^{\circ}$

Comment: Can we use the unit cirlce in some way?

Comment: @nicoledobreva Yes, https://medium.com/@nubtrek/easy-with-sin-a-b-proof-vuja-de-50c15fca3344