# The values of the trigonometric functions of $45^\circ+\alpha$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a new idea about [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973421/trig-values-of-45-circ-alpha) I posted earlier today.

> If $\sin\alpha=\dfrac{4}{5}$ and $\alpha\in(45^\circ;90^\circ)$, find the values of the other trig functions of $\alpha$ and $45^\circ+\alpha$.

Since $\alpha\in\left(45^\circ;90^\circ\right)$, the angle $45^\circ+\alpha$ is obtuse. I was thinking about using the unit circle. The angle $\measuredangle KOO_x^+=\alpha$ and $\measuredangle POO_x^+=45^\circ+\alpha$ where $O$ is the origin and $O_x^+$ denotes the positive $x$-axis. Cosine and sine corespond, respectively, to the $x$- and $y$-coordinate. I have already calculated that $\cos\alpha=\dfrac{3}{5}$ so $K$ is defined as $K(\dfrac{3}{5};\dfrac{4}{5}).$ Can we use some geometric methods from here to find the coordinates of $P$?
[image]

Comment: Geometric derivation possible but not recommended - re : **Why** re-invent the wheel?  Instead, see [Angle Sum Trig Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities).

Comment: why not use formulas for $\cos(a+b)$ ?

Comment: @user2661923, because I haven't studied these formulas and I am not allowed to use them. I want to solve the problem using the things that I know.

Comment: Very good rebuttal.  Someone else may have a more elegant demonstration, capitalizing on $45^\circ$ being a special angle.  For me, I would fall back on the general [proof of angle sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_identities).  That is, if it were me, I would work through the proof, step by step.  Then, assuming that you understand and accept the validity of the proof, then using the formula becomes *fair game*.

Answer (score 1):

The slope of $\text{OK}$ $= \tan\theta = 4/3$, which implies that slope of $\text{OP}$ would be $\tan (\theta+45^\circ)$ which would be equal to $$ \frac{1 + 4/3}{1-4/3} = -7$$
Finding intersection of $y=-7x$ and $x^2+y^2=1$, we get coordinates of $\text{P}$ as $\left(\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{50}}, \dfrac{7}{\sqrt{50}}\right)$.

Another purely geometrical way would be taking centre as $\text{K}$, draw a circle of radius $\pi/4$, *i.e.*,
$$\left(x-\frac35\right)^2 + \left(y-\frac45\right)^2 = \left(\frac\pi4\right)^2$$ And find intersection of this circle with circle of unit radius with origin as centre.

Finding intersection, $\newcommand{\S}{\text{S}}$ $\S_1 - \S_2$:
$$3x+4y = 5 -\frac{5\pi^2}{32}$$
Then find the intersection of this line with any of the circles, you would get $2$ points of which one would be $+45^\circ$ and other would be for $-45^\circ$.